# pwgen - limit special characters

Tags: passwords

I am working on password rotation automation, and one of the task is to generate secure passwords. I found pwgen and it is working great.

How ever I need to limit special characters to ! # $ % - _ = + < > . Any pointers?

```
pwgen -s -N 1 -cny 10
```

For now I am using -r to exclude the ones I do not need. Wondering if there is easier way to opt-in instead of opt-out

```
pwgen -cny -B -1 -r \'\"\@\?\^\&\*\(\)\`\:\~\?\;\:\[\]\{\}\.\,\\\/\| 15
```

Answer (score 1):

There is (currently) no option in `pwgen` to do this (see the author's [README.md](https://github.com/stevenarnold/pwgen/blob/master/resources/README.md)). If you're working on Linux, the following may be an option for you:

```
1) Open $HOME/.bash_rc in a text editor
2) Somewhere near the bottom, add these lines:

# Use with pwgen (password generator) to remove special characters
export PWGEN_SPECIAL=\'\"\@\?\^\&\*\(\)\`\:\~\?\;\:\[\]\{\}\.\,\\\/\|

3) Close, save and open new Terminal
4) pwgen -sy 10 1 -r $PWGEN_SPECIAL
```

Same solution, but a bit less messy than typing a complex exclusion list every time!

Answer (score 0):

I sympathize. The `pwgen` application may not have this functionality built in, but as you've already noted, we can use the `-r` switch to accomplish the inverse. Solution? Create your own inverse function. If you specify the list of all special characters, you can pass your "opt-in" characters and programmatically return the opt-out list.

Sample function:

```
invert() {
  optIn="$1";
  special=\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\=\-\\\]\[\{\}\|\'\;\:\"\/\.\,\<\>\? ;
  grep -oP "[^${optIn}]" <<< "$special" | tr -d '\n';
}
```

Notice that all special characters are defined in the `$special` variable. This list can be modified if necessary. Each character is escaped with a `\`.

Using the function with `pwgen`:

```
pwgen -sync1r "$(invert '\!\#\$\%\-\_\=\+\<\>')" 10
```

Note here that the list of escaped special characters is in single quotes. If you don't put it in single quotes, you may get unexpected and undesired results. That's it. This command will return *one* (`-1` -- see note) ten-character (`10`) secure (`-s`) password that   includes symbols (`-y`), numbers (`-n`), and capitals (`-c`), with the set of symbols being restricted (`-r`) to only those passed into the `invert` function.

In fact, since the `-r` switch can be used to exclude any arbitrary character, this could be used to effect on other non-special characters as well, but that is not within the scope of the original question.

---

**Note: the `-1` switch does not strictly return only one password, but it will in this case unless more passwords are requested*